# Cannot convert varchar to int or subtract them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have following set of SQL statements. The purpose is to find the Selling price of each item.

```
SELECT cost AS 'Price', disc AS 'Discount', (cost-disc) AS 'Selling Price' 
FROM SALE
```

The problem is that `cost, scost, disc` columns are of `Varchar` datatype. So I tried to cast the columns, but it didn't work. No I tried to alter the column datatypes as below:

```
UPDATE SALE 
SET cost = '0.0' 
WHERE cost IS NULL OR ISNUMERIC(cost) = 0;

ALTER TABLE SALE 
    ALTER COLUMN cost DECIMAL(12,0);

UPDATE SALE 
SET scost = '0.0' 
WHERE scost IS NULL OR ISNUMERIC(scost) = 0;

ALTER TABLE SALE 
    ALTER COLUMN scost DECIMAL(12,0);

UPDATE SALE 
SET disc = '0.0' 
WHERE disc IS NULL OR ISNUMERIC(disc) = 0;

ALTER TABLE SALE 
    ALTER COLUMN disc DECIMAL(12,0);
```

The error I am getting in SQL Server Management Studio:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.0' to data type int.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Check for commas in your varchar column. ISNUMERIC won't find them because it will check for all number types (including money).

Comment: The error message suggest cost is int, not varchar. Try the ALTER without the preceding `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to create a new table with the required structure and replicate the datain to new table. Then rename your tables.
Below is the code:

```
update SALE set cost='0.0' where cost='NULL' or cost IS NULL OR ISNUMERIC(cost) = 0;
update SALE set scost='0.0' where scost='NULL' or scost IS NULL OR ISNUMERIC(scost) = 0;
update SALE set disc='0.0' where disc='NULL' or disc IS NULL OR ISNUMERIC(disc) = 0;

CREATE TABLE SALENEW (cost decimal(18,2), scost decimal(18,2), disc decimal(18,2));

INSERT INTO SALENEW SELECT * FROM SALE;

EXEC sp_rename 'SALE', 'SALEBACKUP'; 
EXEC sp_rename 'SALENEW', 'SALE';
```

This will help.

Comment: Yeah, at least with this, now things are working. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Try converting to a decimal type which has enough precision to cover your actual data set, e.g.

```
UPDATE SALE SET cost = '0.0' WHERE cost IS NULL OR ISNUMERIC(cost) = 0;
ALTER TABLE SALE ALTER COLUMN cost DECIMAL(12, 4);
```

The exact error message you are getting seems to be centered around the string literal `0.0` not being convertible to an integer.  But, that doesn't sound right assuming you are trying to convert to a decimal, in which case `0.0` is a perfectly acceptable value.

Comment: Hi,Now it says:

(0 row(s) affected)
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The object 'DF_SALE_scost' is dependent on column 'scost'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 3
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN scost failed because one or more objects access this column.

Comment: @Neetu That looks like an error stemming from a totally different problem in your schema.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the data.  But I would recommend *explicit* conversions:

```
select cost AS Price, disc AS Discount,
       (try_convert(decimal(20, 4), cost) - try_convert(decimal(20, 4), disc) ) as selling_price
from sale;
```

You should not be storing numbers as strings.  You can see if any values are invalid by doing:

```
select cost, disc
from sale
where try_convert(decimal(20, 4), cost) is null or
      try_convert(decimal(20, 4), disc) is null;
```

If no rows are returned, then convert them:

```
alter table alter column cost decimal(20, 4);
alter table alter column disc decimal(20, 4);
```

Note:  This answer uses `decimal(20, 4)`, you can use another relevant type, but decimal seems appropriate for the sample data.

EDIT:

In earlier versions of SQL Server, I would recommend:

```
select cost AS Price, disc AS Discount,
       ((case when cost not like '%[^0-9.]%' and cost not like '%.%.%'
              then convert(decimal(20, 4), cost)
         end) -
        (case when disc not like '%[^0-9]%'  and cost not like '%.%.%'
              then try_convert(decimal(20, 4), disc)
         end)
       ) as selling_price
from sale;
```

You can use similar logic.  I would not recommend `isnumeric()` because the following return "1" -- `'$'`, `'.'`, `'3e4'` -- but none of these convert to a decimal.

Comment: @Neetu - You could also use `CONVERT` instead of `TRY_CONVERT` which is made available from 2012 (mentioned as you have tagged 2008 & 2005)

Comment: It says: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'decimal' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: using CONVERT in place of try_convert, it shows 0 records. even on table scost